# How to change the order of HOOKS in debian iniramfs configuration?

Tags: debian, boot, initramfs, hook

Hello I installed Archlinux to learn and now I'm insalling Debian but the initramfs setup is quite different from the mkinitcpio from Arch.

My question is : where do I find the order in which the HOOKS are loaded ? Also why is there no `keyboard`hook ?

You see I installed Debian on an encrypted partition and when it loads and prompt for the password I have to wait 2min before the keyboard gets activated and I can put in the key, I thought I could avoid this problem with the hook keyboard but can't find it and don't know where I can see the hooks order. Can you provide me with directions ?

Comment: I am glad you are trying Arch and now Debian, but, when starting with a new distro, it is best to read the distro specific documentation. See https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard#Set_Keyboard_Layout_in_initramfs and https://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/ch-initramfs.html

Comment: also http://www.kasploosh.com/weblog/14000/14016-debian_jessie_usb_keyboard.html , sort of depends on your keyboard

Comment: @bodhi.zazen unfortunately the solution in the kasploosh weblog isn't working :/ it's so painful to have to wait 2minutes to be allowed to enter the passphrase as the rest of the boot is instantaneous, I wish someone come with a solution, what is the config file for maybe i can change somehting in there ?